# LWC - Alternate Button Icon in lightning-datatable based on results

Tags: lightning-web-components

How do I conditionally alternate a button icon displayed through a lightning-datatable? I would like to change the button icon based on data coming from the Apex method? The AccountContactRelation.Roles field specifically. So if that field contains a certain Role I want to change the button icon (iconName) from utility:add to standard:task2. All suggestions are appreciated. Thanks ahead of time!

[image]

acr.js

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { getRecord, getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import getpeople from '@salesforce/apex/controller.getpeople'; 
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACR_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/AccountContactRelation';
import saveACR from '@salesforce/apex/controller.saveACRTaxInvoiceRole';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class TaxRelatedACRs extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @track people = [];
    @track hasACRs = false;

    @track columns = [
        {
            label: 'Action',
            type: 'button-icon',
            initialWidth: 75,
            typeAttributes: {
                iconName: 'utility:add',
                title: 'Assign',
                variant: 'border-filled',
                alternativeText: 'Assign'
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'Name',
            fieldName: 'contactname',
            type: 'text',
            sortable: false
        },
        {
            label: 'Email',
            fieldName: 'contactemail',
            type: 'text',
            sortable: false
        },
        {
            label: 'Roles',
            fieldName: 'roles',
            type: 'text',
            sortable: false
        }

    ];

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACR_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;
    
    @wire(getpeople,{recordId:'$recordId'}) 
    wiredPeople(result){
        this.wiredPeopleResults = result;
        let {data, error} = result;
        if(data){
            console.log('data-->'+JSON.stringify(result.data));
            this.people = data;
            this.error = undefined;

        } else if (error) {
            this.people = undefined;
            this.error = error;

        }
    }

    // Row Action event to update the AccountContactRelation record
    handleRowAction(event) {
        let row = event.detail.row;
        console.log('row-->'+JSON.stringify(row)); 
        this.record = row;
        this.isLoading = true;

        saveACR({jsonObject: JSON.stringify(this.record)}).then(res =>{ 

            console.log(res); 
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Person Assigned',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );

            return refreshApex(this.wiredPeopleResults);

        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err); 

        });
        
    }

}
```

acr.html

```
<template>

    <lightning-card title="Related Contacts" icon-name="standard:people"> 

        <lightning-datatable data={people} 
                             columns={columns} 
                             key-field="id"
                             onrowselection={handleRowSelection}
                             hide-checkbox-column="true"
                             onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                             ></lightning-datatable>

                              
    </lightning-card> 

</template>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
            iconName: 'utility:add',
```

To:

```
            iconName: { fieldName: 'rowIcon' },
```

And then add the attribute to each row:

```
this.people = data.map(item => ({ ...item, rowIcon: item.Role == 'Some Value'?'standard:task2':'utility:add' }));
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response. The third part in that is where I struggle to get my mind around. Does that go in the wired service? Also what does the "..." represent? Is that saying I want that to happen on each row?

Comment: @user891859 Yes, replace the this.people = data; with the new version. The ... operator is the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It's used for a few things, one of which is to copy an object's properties to a new object. We do this because the data object is immutable (cannot be modified), so we need to copy it to add a new value to it.

Comment: This worked great - thank you for your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to use this approach to also conditionally hide the icon? Happy to post as a separate question but not sure it's worth it. When I have that field not populated, it still shows a border.